# A section of my page does goes off the page on tablets

Tags: html, ios, css

The middle section of my page goes off the side of the screen when using an ipad or other devices, yet other elements seem to be fine.

Does anybody know why ?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwOzOw

```
<div class="mid-section">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="row-fluid">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1 class="text-center">So, What can we do for you?</h1>
                <p class="text-center"> Placeholder Placeholder Placeholder 
                   </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Something is pushing the viewport off the screen, try checking or inspecting all your divs and see if one has a fixed width or something

Answer (score 0):

div.mid-section has large left and right padding. When combined with the fixed widths you give div.container, it means that the total width of div.mid-section is greater than screen width.

Either adjust the fixed widths of div.container or let div.container's width be fluid.